# Azure B2C authentication problem- MsalBroadcastService subscribe code not executing

Tags: angular, azure-ad-b2c

Hi I have implemented Azure B2C authentication in my Angular project using the sample tutorial  given in https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-javascript-angular-tutorial. When running the sample it is fine. But when I copied the exact code to my own Angular SPA with an backend API, I am able to show the Microsoft login page and upon logging in, it is showing the ID token in the browser dev tool, but the button that is showing on the page(after redirecting back to my app post-Login)  is still the Login button and not the Logout button. Upon debugging I find that the Subscribe code for the msalBroadcastService.inProgress$ observable is not executed. After trying to find out why this is so, unlike in the Sample it is executing this code(this.setLoginDisplay()) well as expected, setting the loginDisplay to true so that it shows the Logout button. But there is definitely a problem in the Subscribe method and I don't know why. I am attaching below the component and its html and also the Msal auth config file

```js
 import { LogLevel, Configuration, BrowserCacheLocation, InteractionType } from '@azure/msal-browser';

 const isIE = window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE ") > -1 || window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Trident/") > -1;
 
 export const b2cPolicies = {
     names: {
         signUpSignIn: "B2C_1_B2C_app_sign_in",
         editProfile: "B2C_1_B2C_app_profile_edit"
     },
     authorities: {
         signUpSignIn: {
             authority: "https://spb2c.b2clogin.com/spb2c.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_B2C_app_sign_in",
         },
         editProfile: {
             authority: "https://spb2c.b2clogin.com/spb2c.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_B2C_app_profile_edit"
         }
     },
     authorityDomain: "spb2c.b2clogin.com"
 };
 
  export const msalConfig: Configuration = {
     auth: {
         clientId: '38c350b0-ffcb-5669-9af8-d07561d8a966', // This is the ONLY mandatory field that you need to supply.
         authority: b2cPolicies.authorities.signUpSignIn.authority, // Defaults to "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common"
         knownAuthorities: [b2cPolicies.authorityDomain], // Mark your B2C tenant's domain as trusted.
         redirectUri: '/', // Points to window.location.origin. You must register this URI on Azure portal/App Registration.
         postLogoutRedirectUri: '/', // Indicates the page to navigate after logout.
         navigateToLoginRequestUrl: true, // If "true", will navigate back to the original request location before processing the auth code response.
        },
     cache: {
         cacheLocation: BrowserCacheLocation.LocalStorage, // Configures cache location. "sessionStorage" is more secure, but "localStorage" gives you SSO between tabs.
         storeAuthStateInCookie: isIE, // Set this to "true" if you are having issues on IE11 or Edge
     },
     system: {
         loggerOptions: {
             loggerCallback(logLevel: LogLevel, message: string) {
                 console.log(message);
             },
             logLevel: LogLevel.Verbose,
             piiLoggingEnabled: false
         }
     }
 }
 

 
 export const protectedResources={
     powerfishApi:{
         endpoint: "https://localhost:44358/api/",
         scopes:["https://spb2c.onmicrosoft.com/pow-api/fapi.read",
                 "https://spb2c.onmicrosoft.com/pow-api/fapi.write"]
     }     
 }

export const loginRequest = {
    scopes: []
};
```

```js
import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, EventEmitter, Inject, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

import { MsalService, MsalBroadcastService, MSAL_GUARD_CONFIG, MsalGuardConfiguration } from '@azure/msal-angular';
import { InteractionType, InteractionStatus, PopupRequest, RedirectRequest, AuthenticationResult, EventMessage, AuthError, EventType } from '@azure/msal-browser';
import { Subject, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, filter, takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { b2cPolicies } from '../../auth-config';

declare var $: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navigation',
  templateUrl: './navigation.component.html'
})
export class NavigationComponent {
  @Output()
  toggleSidebar = new EventEmitter<void>();

  @Input()
  user:any = {countryCode:""};

  public showSearch = false;

  isIframe = false;
  loginDisplay = false;
  private readonly _destroying$ = new Subject<void>();

  constructor(@Inject(MSAL_GUARD_CONFIG) private msalGuardConfig: MsalGuardConfiguration,
            private authService: MsalService,
            private msalBroadcastService: MsalBroadcastService,
            private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit(){
    debugger;

      /**
     * You can subscribe to MSAL events as shown below. For more info,
     * visit: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-angular/docs/v2-docs/events.md
     */
    this.msalBroadcastService.inProgress$
    .pipe(
      filter((status: InteractionStatus) => status === InteractionStatus.None),
      takeUntil(this._destroying$)
    )
    .subscribe(() => {
      this.setLoginDisplay();
    });

        this.route.paramMap
        .subscribe(params => {
          console.log(params);
        }
      );
  }

  setLoginDisplay() {
    this.loginDisplay = this.authService.instance.getAllAccounts().length > 0;
  }

  login(userFlowRequest?: RedirectRequest | PopupRequest) {
    if (this.msalGuardConfig.interactionType === InteractionType.Popup) {
      if (this.msalGuardConfig.authRequest) {
        this.authService.loginPopup({...this.msalGuardConfig.authRequest, ...userFlowRequest} as PopupRequest)
          .subscribe((response: AuthenticationResult) => {
            this.authService.instance.setActiveAccount(response.account);
          });
      } else {
        this.authService.loginPopup(userFlowRequest)
          .subscribe((response: AuthenticationResult) => {
            this.authService.instance.setActiveAccount(response.account);
          });
      }
    } else {
      if (this.msalGuardConfig.authRequest){
        this.authService.loginRedirect({...this.msalGuardConfig.authRequest, ...userFlowRequest} as RedirectRequest);
      } else {
        this.authService.loginRedirect(userFlowRequest);
      }
    }
  }

  logout() {
    this.authService.logout();
  }

  editProfile() {
    let editProfileFlowRequest = {
      scopes: ["openid"],
      authority: b2cPolicies.authorities.editProfile.authority,
    };

    this.login(editProfileFlowRequest);
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this._destroying$.next(undefined);
    this._destroying$.complete();
  }

}
```

```html
<!-- ============================================================== -->
<!-- toggle and nav items -->
<!-- ============================================================== -->
<ul class="navbar-nav float-left mr-auto align-items-center">
    <li class="nav-item d-none d-md-block ">
        <a (click)="toggleSidebar.emit()" class="nav-link sidebartoggler waves-effect waves-light" href="javascript:void(0)">
            <i class="mdi mdi-menu font-24"></i>
        </a>
    </li>
    <!-- <li class="d-none d-md-block">
        <form class="app-search">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..."> 
        </form>
    </li> -->
</ul>
<!-- ============================================================== -->
<!-- Right side toggle and nav items -->
<!-- ============================================================== -->
<ul class="navbar-nav float-right">
    
    <li class="mr-2 d-flex align-items-center">
        <button mat-raised-button *ngIf="!loginDisplay" (click)="login()">Login</button>
        <button mat-raised-button color="accent" *ngIf="loginDisplay" (click)="logout()">Logout</button>
        <label class="m-0 mr-3">{{user.countryCode}}</label>
        <div class="dropdown profile_img">
            <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                <img src="assets/images/users/defaultUser.jpeg" class="profile-image rounded-circle" alt="LoggedIn User">
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Please can someone help identify this problem.

Comment: Hi! Did you manage to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem adding the selector *app redirect* in index.html file